# Deleting Module History CVS

Tags: module, cvs, history

I'm searching for a way to delete one module's complete history.

I'm starting a project and there's already one temporary module someone else created with the name I should use for this module.

The repository has some testing commits and changes that I don't want to keep.

I want to be able to completely delete this one module and all of it's history, but keeping the other modules and their history. This is not negotiable!

PS: I know no one uses CVS anymore, We're in the middle of migrating to a DVCS, but in the mean time we need to get this working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are absolutely sure you never want the module again, you can just delete the entire folder from the repository. If you *do* want to retain the information then you can just rename the folder and you should be able to check out the module with this new name.

Comment: That's the thing, I want to use the same module name, with a different structure. But I don't want it to retain any history...

Comment: Go ahead and just delete the folder from the repository then. You'll have to create the module fresh.